# How to get tags of many UIButtons but with same action selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a method that shows 10 (or more) UIButtons. I have here a code as to how I showed these buttons..

```
-(void)showButtons{
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 94);  //Assume x and y have values
  **button.tag = i + 1000;**
  [button setBackgroundImage:[_cardImages objectAtIndex:i]  
      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:)   
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view add subview:button];
  [button release];
```

}
}

```
-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender{
// I would like to print here button.tag, but I always get an error
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to typecast the sender here because **id** types don't have the **tag** property.
The new code will be

```
-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender{
   UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSLog(@"Tag of button pressed:%d",pressedButton.tag);
}
```

Comment: Or you can say `[sender tag]`, or you can change the declaration of the method to `-(IBAction)myMethod:(UIButton *)sender`.

Comment: tried this:
-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender{
   UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSLog(@"Tag of button pressed:%d",pressedButton.tag);
}

I got this error:
[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6f99140

Comment: I think we would need to know more about the context to figure what's going on here. I believe that Kumar's answer is correct.

Comment: Well then you have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that you have connected to the `myMethod`.  You need to edit your question and describe how the tap gesture recognizer is set up, and paste in any code that deals with the tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: @robmayoff - sorry, I'm editing my code now. I'll be using the addTarget:action method of the UIButton, instead of using the tapGesture. I just realized I was using the tapGesture in calling the myMethod function (which is why I can't print the tag). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will get the result by printing value of sender.tag instead of button.tag

```
-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
}
```

Comment: i tried this inside the IBAction 

  int tag = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"%d",tag);

Comment: An id doesn't have a tag property. You have to cast sender to UIButton. I think Kumar's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the UIButton's UIView and then accessing it's TAG property. So modifying Amresh Kumar's code:

```
-(IBAction)myMethod {
 UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
 NSLog(@"Tag of button pressed:%d",pressedButton.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: A UIButton doesn't HAVE a view; a UIButton IS a view. Kumar's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your myMethod's defination should be like this

I use the same way to get tag of sender.

```
-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"%d",[sender tag]);
}
```

No type casting is needed, you may get tag of sender, it doesn't matter the datatype of it.